# Name Matching in single column and required result in next column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have very long database around 4 to 5 lac rows data, i want result in next column with any similar name.

I am trying to used Fuzzy but i dont have unique list for match.

[image]

Comment: How did you get the result column? Did you sort the data or based on the highlight data in Column Name?

Comment: I put it manually, i want highlight result through any function or formula.

Answer (score 0):

**To solve the issue you need VBA (Macro):**

[image]

**How it works:**

- Either press **Alt+F11** or **Right Click** Sheet TAB & from poped up menu click **View Code**.
- **Copy** & **Paste** this code as *standard module.*
- **RUN** the Macro.

  ```
   Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal rngSel As Range)
    Set rngTable = [I2:K17]
     If rngSel.Count > 1 Or Intersect(rngSel, rngTable) Is Nothing Then End
     For Each rngCell In rngTable
  rngCell.Interior.ColorIndex = IIf(rngCell.Value = rngSel.Value, 27, -4142)
     Next
   End Sub
  ```

**N.B.**

- In this code `rngTable = [I2:K17]` Cell references, as well as Color code `27, -4142` are editable.

Answer (score 0):

The approach I would take is one of two ways:

1) Use a Lookup table and try to exhaustively make up all the possible variations that idiot users can think of for the same thing, or use source data and remove duplicates to get the known list of stupid options. This is the sort of thing I have to do when migrating contact data with "job title" - the record to date is 67 different ways of styling or spelling "Managing Director" (MD, M.D., M Dir, Manging Driector, etc). This approach is great for a one-off on historical data - in my case once the data was migrated we used drop-down pick lists to stop users just causing the same old problem in a new system.

2) Use a set of rules to "throw away" irrelevant information that you do not consider necessary to discriminate between things that match. A bunch of nested SUBSTITUTE functions replacing short strings with "" does the trick. Replace punctuation marks like . - / : first, then things like (PVT) and Ltd and Limited - if any of these short strings are ambiguous and could occur inside another word, include a space before, after or both. A good example is replacing "Co " but not "Co" to avoid ending up with "mpany" or "bblers". Make the outermost SUBSTITUTE " " for "" (ie lose the spaces last). This deals with "A B C Foods", but leaves the spaces till last so you can still parse strings without losing bits of words.

I am assuming you consider "ABC Foods" to be the same as "ABC Foods (PVT) Ltd."

Now create a list of all the "right" answers. Create a second column to the left using your formula, then copy > paste special > values to "flatten" this. Now in your main data, use your substitutions to reduce the name to its minimalistic format, then use that as a lookup value to return the "right" version. You can use a helper column for the SUBSTITUTEs or do it all in one go.

This approach takes a few goes to get right and spot all the bits that can be safely thrown away, but is then more robust if the source data can contain new, unanticipated errors in future.

Remember: If you try to make it idiot-proof, someone will just go and fetch a bigger idiot.